# How to add value attribute to option element from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have two drop down lists, second is dependent on the first one. What I don´t know is how add different value to node.value (value of option element).

EDIT: At this moment I have same value in textContent and in value of html option element but I need to add different value from textContent.
e.g. Inhabitants

```js
var moduly = [];
moduly['1'] = ["Inhabitants", "Married"];
moduly['2'] = ["German", "French", "English"];
moduly['3'] = ["Houses", "Estates"];
moduly['4'] = ["Surface area", "Meadow area"];

document.querySelector("select[name='modulSelect']").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var element = moduly[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()];
  var elementvalue = mvalue[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()];
  if (element) {
    var select = document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']").cloneNode();
    var node = document.createElement("option");
    node.value = 0;
    node.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    node.setAttribute("selected", true);
    node.textContent = "Choose module";
    select.appendChild(node);
    moduly[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()].forEach(function(element) {
      var node = document.createElement("option");
      node.value = element;
      node.textContent = element;
      select.appendChild(node);
    });
    document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']").parentElement.replaceChild(select, document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']"));
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="modulSelect" name="modulSelect">
    <option value="1">Demographics</option>
    <option value="2">Nation</option>
    <option value="3">Property</option>
    <option value="4">Area</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a var that isn't defined, which throws an error:

```js
var elementvalue = mvalue[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()];
```

Because the var `elementvalue` is also not used, you can comment that line out or delete it. Furthermore you try to clone a `select` element with the name `itemSelect` which doesn't exist in this example code. The following line is missing:

```html
<select id="itemSelect" name="itemSelect"></select>
```

Fix both errors and yout code should work as expected.

**Working example:** (i added a disabled `option` like in the second `select` so that you can select the first `option` "Demographics" and renamed the second disabled `option` from "Choose modul" to "Choose item" so that you can differentiate between both)

```js
var moduly = [];
moduly['1'] = ["Inhabitants", "Married"];
moduly['2'] = ["German", "French", "English"];
moduly['3'] = ["Houses", "Estates"];
moduly['4'] = ["Surface area", "Meadow area"];

document.querySelector("select[name='modulSelect']").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var element = moduly[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()];
  //var elementvalue = mvalue[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()];
  if (element) {
    var select = document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']").cloneNode();
    var node = document.createElement("option");
    node.value = 0;
    node.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    node.setAttribute("selected", true);
    node.textContent = "Choose item";
    select.appendChild(node);
    moduly[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()].forEach(function(element) {
      var node = document.createElement("option");
      node.value = element;
      node.textContent = element;
      select.appendChild(node);
    });
    document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']").parentElement.replaceChild(select, document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']"));
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="modulSelect" name="modulSelect">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose module</option>
    <option value="1">Demographics</option>
    <option value="2">Nation</option>
    <option value="3">Property</option>
    <option value="4">Area</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="itemSelect" name="itemSelect"></select>
</form>
```

---

If you want different value/content pairs you can nest your `moduly` array one step deeper. Change the array for example from:

```js
moduly['3'] = ["Houses", "Estates"];
```

to

```js
moduly['3'] = [["10", "Houses"], ["11", "Estates"]];
```

Then you just need to output the data with array notation:

```js
node.value = element[0];
node.textContent = element[1];
```

```js
var moduly = [];
moduly['1'] = [["5", "Inhabitants"], ["6", "Married"]];
moduly['2'] = [["7", "German"], ["8", "French"], ["9", "English"]];
moduly['3'] = [["10", "Houses"], ["11", "Estates"]];
moduly['4'] = [["12", "Surface area"], ["13", "Meadow area"]];

document.querySelector("select[name='modulSelect']").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var element = moduly[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()];
  //var elementvalue = mvalue[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()];
  if (element) {
    var select = document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']").cloneNode();
    var node = document.createElement("option");
    node.value = 0;
    node.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    node.setAttribute("selected", true);
    node.textContent = "Choose item";
    select.appendChild(node);
    moduly[this.value.toString().toLowerCase()].forEach(function(element) {
      var node = document.createElement("option");
      node.value = element[0];
      node.textContent = element[1];
      select.appendChild(node);
    });
    document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']").parentElement.replaceChild(select, document.querySelector("select[name='itemSelect']"));
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="modulSelect" name="modulSelect">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose module</option>
    <option value="1">Demographics</option>
    <option value="2">Nation</option>
    <option value="3">Property</option>
    <option value="4">Area</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="itemSelect" name="itemSelect"></select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer - but what i need is to add different value to node.value element. At this moment I have same value in textContext and in value attributes of option element but I need add different.

Comment: Thanks, this works like charm - example with multidimensional array